# button not working in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html

This works:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function lala() {
            console.log("lala");
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="lala()">lala</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

But having that in jsfiddle works not:

```
<button onclick="lala()">lala</button>

function lala() {
    console.log("lala");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/715kha38/

> Uncaught ReferenceError: lala is not defined

I saw some old answers on stackoverflow regarding this problem but those seem to be invalid those days.

Comment: just use `no wrap in head` mode

Comment: Click on text `JAVASCRIPT`, set load type to `NO WRAP - BODY`

Answer (score 0):

Please change Load type in java script section select

```
No wrap - in <head>
```